# Some Task Tags are not recognized in Eclipse 3.6

Tags: eclipse

I am fairly new to Eclipse, and I am attempting to define some new Task Tags in the

*"Preferences" -> "General" -> "Editors" -> "Structured Text" -> "Task Tags*" setting.

Of the three I have defined ("???", "TEMP", "SYM"), only the "???" is being recognized and imported into the "Tasks" panel.

Does anyone know why the other two tags are not being recognized?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean "???" is literally the tag you're seeing?  Task Tags are set in more than one location--do the files you're working with correspond to the content types listed on that tab of the preference page?

Answer (score 0):

Boy I know how late this is but in case anyone else has the problem....
Tags displayed in the Task View are set using the Eclipse/Preferences/Java/Compiler/Task Tags.
Adding a tag is as simple as selecting "New" and giving your tag a name and level of importance.  If after adding a tag in Preferences and then in a file type that is enabled for tags (set in the same preference pane in the filters tab) and the tag does not show up in the task view then the problem may be that the plugin is set to "configure project specific settings".  Return to the preference pane mentioned above. Select your tag. Select form the upper right hand corner of the pane "configure project specific settings" and either clear it's project specific status or allow it to use your tag.